# Issue with iterm2 console

Tags: unix, command-line, iterm2

I am new to iterm2 and mac system.I installed

```
Oh my Zsh
```

from previous  experience and some recommendations. My aliases are stored in bash profile. Yet I am able to work just fine. When launched iterm2, I am getting this error in each tab:

```
' /Users/user/.bash_profile:193: bad option: -t '
' /Users/user/.zshrc:255: bad option: -t '
```

Is this an error. Or what does it mean?
Did I do something wrong. Or do I just need to do something ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error lines and commented them out.